# Xcode6 Compile error only when using device arm_neon.h

Tags: ios8, xcode6, glkit

We just recently updated to Xcode6, and we a lot of errors in arm_neon.h we are using glkit framework to build our app.

Here the error in arm_neon.h:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:69:24: Neon vector size must be 64 or 128 bits
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:978:47: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int64x1_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:1001:10: C-style cast from scalar 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:1020:10: C-style cast from vector '**attribute**((**vector_size**(8 * sizeof(signed char)))) signed char' to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:1032:51: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int8x8_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:1297:10: First two arguments to __builtin_shufflevector must be vectors
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:1389:10: First two arguments to __builtin_shufflevector must be vectors
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3120:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int8x8_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3142:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3164:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int32x2_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3186:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'int64x1_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3208:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'uint8x8_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3230:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'uint16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3252:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'uint32x2_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3274:10: C-style cast from vector 'float16x4_t' to vector 'uint64x1_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3282:10: C-style cast from vector 'int8x8_t' to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3284:10: C-style cast from vector 'int16x4_t' to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3286:10: C-style cast from vector 'int32x2_t' to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include/arm_neon.h:3288:10: C-style cast from vector 'int64x1_t' to vector 'float16x4_t' of different size

It ONLY occurs when we tried to build it in device, it builds well on simulators.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i did a temporary fix for this, directly editing **arm_neon.h** changing the `__fp16` to a short data type.

edit:

ultimately we found out that our project was defining `__fp16` to something else causing the problem.